# How to check properties in aws sdk 2.x objects in unit tests?

Tags: java, aws-sdk, encapsulation

I am trying to reproduce unit tests for aws sdk 1.x java code after upgrading to aws sdk 2.x. I'm not sure how to reproduce the unit tests with the new sdk.

The old sdk used simple getter and setter functions I could access like so:

```
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfiguration.setConnectiontimeout(50000);
clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(150000);
```

I could unit-test that with:

```
assertThat(clientConfiguration.getConnectionTimeout(), is(50000));
assertThat(clientConfiguration.getSocketTimeout(), is(150000));
```

However, in aws sdk 2.x, objects aren't built with constructors and setter functions but with static builders like so:

```
configuration = ApacheHttpClient.builder().proxyConfiguration(proxyConfig)
.connectionTimeout(50000)
.socketTimeout(150000)
.build();
```

The trouble is, the resulting object has no getter-functions to access properties like maxConnection and socketTimeout, so I do not know how to test. They're not even private properties; the resulting ApacheHttpClient object has private child objects which themselves contain these different fields. I could use ReflectionTestUtils to access the child objects' private fields as this is a unit test, but I prefer not to since the test becomes brittle and breaks if future sdk upgrades change those private fields.

How do I write unit tests to verify the internal state of these aws objects that do not provide getter functions? For example, how do I test maxConnection and socketTimeout in the above object?

Thanks!